# Manipulating output string in c#

Tags: c#

I have a task killer program that has a listbox of current running processes. After an item is selected, a button click runs code to kill the selected task.  That all works fine, but what I need help with is manipulating the string output on my form that displays what the last task killed was.  For instance, if I open up calculator and kill that task, my string output is: "System.Diagnostics.Process (calc)". I would prefer if this was to just say "calc".  So I need to be able to strip the "System.Diagnostics.Process ( )"

```
    public bool KillProcess(ListBox PList, TextBox Killed)
    {
        bool Kill = true;
        string x = "";
        Killed.Text = "";


        if (PList.SelectedItem != null)
        {

            foreach (Process p in Process.GetProcesses(Environment.MachineName))
            {
                x = PList.SelectedItem.ToString();

                if (p.ProcessName.Equals(x))
                {

                    try
                    {
                        p.Kill();

     //*************** Here is where I have the process killed placed into a textbox
                    //Which I would like to not say "System.Diagnostics.Process..."

                        Killed.Text = p.ToString();
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(p.ProcessName.ToString() + " cannot be killed. ", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                        Kill = false;
                    }
                }


            }
        }
        else 
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please select a process to be killed.", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            Kill = false;
        }

        return Kill;
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you simply use p.ProcessName?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of

```
Killed.Text = p.ToString();
```

try

```
Killed.Text = p.ProcessName;
```

Also, as a separate note, you don’t need to say `p.ProcessName.ToString()` elsewhere, because `p.ProcessName` is already a string.

Comment: @Richard since it works, you might want to mark this answer with a green checkbox next to it.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use [`p.ProcessName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.processname.aspx).

You could also access the `p.StartInfo` to get into the [`ProcessStartInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.aspx) which also gives you further information about the process (such as the file name) - this *could* be useful.